# Feller textbook question: Show that the (conditional) probability of a triple occupancy of some cells equals $\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question is already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703871/show-that-the-conditional-probability-of-a-triple-occupancy-of-some-cells-equa) . But there is no direct answer given there. It is a question from Feller's book Volume 1. According to the book, answer to the question is $\frac{1}{4}$. But my calculation never gets me 0.25.

If my calculation is right, answer to the question is

$$
\frac{ 5 \frac{7!}{3!1!1!1!1!} \frac{5!}{4!1!} }{5^7}
$$
which is 0.2688 which is not $\frac{1}{4}$.  Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator will be $\dbinom{7}{3,1,1}\times\frac{5!}{4!} = N, say $

The denominator will be $N + \left[\dbinom{7}{2,2,1,1,1}\times \frac{5!}{2!3!}\right]$

[The conditionality is on only 2 cells being empty, and the reference you gave mentioned that none of the remaining 5 cells were to be empty]